# php League-CSV: floating numbers are rendered as text in the CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I am using [League CSV](https://github.com/thephpleague/csv) package (v9.0) to write data into CSV file, Unfortunately it exports floating numbers as a text and not as numbers. I want them to remain as numbers so that basic operations such as SUM, Count can be done using the Excel or OpenOffice.

Here is the data that i want to insert into the csv file.

```
$data = array(
 [
   'header1' => 12.02,
   'header2' => 32.4,
   'header3' => "sadsa",
   'header4' => "rete",
   'header5' => "tet"
 ],
 [
   'header1' => 14.02,
   'header2' => 35.4,
   'header3' => "blabla2",
   'header4' => "rete",
    'header5' => "tet"
  ],
);
```

To insert the data using League CSV

```
$writer = Writer::createFromPath($filePath,'w+');
//$header = $this->getHeaderFromData($FileData);
$writer->setDelimiter(";");
//$writer->insertOne($header);
$writer->insertAll(new \ArrayIterator($data));
```

also same result using fputcsv()

```
$file = fopen("/tmp/test.csv","w");

    foreach ($data as $value) {
        fputcsv($file,$value,";",'"');
    }
fclose($file);
```

CSV Output: for some reason both `fputcsv()` and `League-CSV` adds single quote and it works when i remove it.

[image: output of CSV file]

output of Gedit:

[image: output of Gedit]

Comment: maybe round them up to the nearest whole number before save? Tried that? `32.4` should give `32` etc.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot round them to a whole number since we have to pay external employees based on the numbers and the file is huge  with over 1000 entries; then there will be huge difference in the calculation

Comment: Can you show an example of what your CSV file should look like with the array posted? @GabfHann

Comment: Are you sure it's the CSV library that is doing the conversion (you have the numbers encapsulated by `"` in the *.csv file) and not the Excel/Writer? Depending on the machine current locale the decimals can be separated by `.` and `,` - if it is the second then maybe try exporting `str_replace($float, '.', ',')`

Comment: Do you get the same results using `fputcsv()`? If not, you should probably take it up with the League-CSV developers.

Comment: @MichalBieda yes its the CSV library doing its encapsulated with `'` (single quotes) when i remove them in the csv file its displayed as numbers and I can SUM, Count etc...

Comment: @jeroen  they are rendered as text instead of numbers using `fputcsv()`. I have added the code using `fputcsv()`

Comment: @GabfHann please check the csv file in any plain text editor and see if the `'` are there. It may be appended when importing CSV into Excel - also when opening the file there should be some kind of setup where you can select what kind of column it is (text, numeric etc)

Comment: there isnt any single quote when i open using gedit.

Comment: @GabfHann then it is not a problem of League-CSV nor fputcsv() but how your OpenOffice Calc is opening/interpreting it. When you open the CSV select the column (in the import dialog) and change its type to numeric... or export to *.xslx with different library

Comment: okay, I got it fixed... yes its the openOffice and the excel are interpreting wrongly.. Thanks for the help :)